# Keep getting message `404:: command not found` everytime opening terminal

Tags: command-line, bash

I just realized that I keep getting message `404:: command not found` every time I open terminal. I don't remember what I installed right before getting this message:

[image]

I can't find it in any of bash's startup files:

```
$ grep 404 -H ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/.bash.login \
              ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile  \
             /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2> /dev/null
$
```

I also ran `PS4='${BASH_SOURCE}:${LINENO} ' bash -lxe`, you can find the full output can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/petrabarus/5e617b8e99d560137733f8e868a1cec2).

Comment: Oh wow. Something really strange is going on here. Do you have any idea what you might have changed to cause this? Were you editing any configuration files or something? @muru this is an odd one.

Comment: What's in your `/etc/bash_completion.d/docker-compose` ?

Comment: Also, I just realized you ran `ps $$` after running `bash -lxe`. Could you open a new terminal, run `ps $$` and just confirm that the output contains  `bash`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This part of your [`bash -lxe` output](https://gist.github.com/petrabarus/5e617b8e99d560137733f8e868a1cec2#file-1-txt-L823):

```
///usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:1981 . /etc/bash_completion.d/docker-compose
////etc/bash_completion.d/docker-compose:1 404: Not Found
////etc/bash.bashrc:57 '[' -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ']'
////etc/bash.bashrc:58 /usr/lib/command-not-found -- 404:
404:: command not found
////etc/bash.bashrc:59 return 127
```

reads to me that you have a `/etc/bash_completion.d/docker-compose` that starts off with `404:`. I'm guessing at some point you tried to download that configuration file from somewhere and instead wound up saving an HTTP error message.

That file should be plain text; you can use your preferred text editor on it (you should need to use sudo/sudoedit/etc. to modify it).

PS: I suggest in the future you review downloaded files before installing them—not only to notice error messages, but also to see what they do (especially important if you don't fully trust the site its coming from, or if its served over HTTP instead of HTTPS), and if there is any customization needed for your particular setup.

Comment: Thanks a lot I just looked inside `/etc/bash_completion.d/docker- compose`  and there is only a line `404 not found`. I just removed it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error : upon opening a new shell, I got the message :

```
-bash: 404:: command not found
```

I chased it successively in :

- `~/.bashrc`
- `/etc/bash_completion`
- `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`
- which ended with `/etc/bash_completion.d/docker-compose` that only had `404: Not Found` inside

Back to my `docker-compose` setup, I found I made a typo in the command installing the corresponding bash completion. The command to use to install (or restore) this bash completion can be found in the [Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/completion/#install-command-completion).

Answer (score 0):

i had the same as everyone above, an 404 error in the file `/etc/bash_completion.d/docker-compose`.
Deleting it fixed the issue.